# Sqlalchemy: Database delete error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For the following function

```
def deleteMenuItem(restaurant_id,menu_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(id = menu_id)
        session.delete(item)
        session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('showMenu',restaurant_id =restaurant_id))
    else:
        return render_template('deletemenu.html',restaurant_id=restaurant_id,menu_id=menu_id)
```

When I try to delete an item. I get the following error

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError UnmappedInstanceError: Class
>   'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query' is not mapped

The error can be fixed if I do the following change to the code

```
item = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(id = menu_id).one()
```

I am not sure why the .one() fixes the problem. Since the query itself will always find one result. So why is the .one() needed?

Comment: `.one()` returns the object found. `...filter_by(...)` returns a Query object.

Comment: @Holloway that's an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(id=menu_id)` returns a `Query` object that can be used to filter or order the results, not the results themselves.

`one()` returns the first object the query finds.

When you try to delete the query, it complains that the `Query` object is not mapped.

Docs are [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html). The `Query` object also has a `delete` method that will delete all matched objects.